# counting patterns in image

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

I'm working on an algorithm that counts patterns (bars) in a specific image. It seemed to me very simple at the first look, but I realized the complexity quickly. 
I have tried simple thresholding, template matching (small sliding windows), edge detection...
I have just few images like this one. so I think that a machine learning algorithm can't give better results! but I still need suggestions.
[image]

Comment: Are you working in a specific language? that could help others give you better answers. I think MAYBE you can try some sort of watershed algorithm, maybe use it with the edge map. another option might be converting the image to binary and using dilation and erosion to separate the bars

Comment: Thanks for answering. Any language is welcome. I think Matlab will be nice. For production, Opencv will perhaps be the best. Anyway, this is not my deal now. I have tried different segmentation algorithms (watershed and edge also) but still the results very dependent on parameters.  Morphological operations (dilation and erosion) are more dangerous. some ROIs can disappear for ever!. Thanks again.

Comment: I also tried thresholding (Bradley local image thresholding), results are so-so.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have enough data from your images. You need to crop from your images only the bars. You would get several dozens of small images for each image. After that you can resize all the images to some predefined size (for example 24X24 pixels) use a descriptor like HOG and SVM for the learning. For the false just use any other areas from your images.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Amitay. I had a similar idea with template matching. I have tried to crop templates (based on centroids of detected objects after random binarization) and performed template matching on gradient magnitudes (HOG uses directions), and sum maximum matches. the results were encouraging, but still not satisfied. I will try your idea with HOG gradient directions, perhaps with a set of examples. I think that the size of template will be a big problem for automation, but I'll try anyway. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This may not work in all cases,  but since these are round bars, you can also try using circle detection. Both matlab([find circles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/detect-and-measure-circular-objects-in-an-image.html)) and opencv([hough circle transform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html)) support this hough circle transformation. One issue is that you have to play with the parameters a bit (matlab is more simplistic than open cv) but that is true of almost any method.

These methods work better with larger images so I resized yours. You also need to know the radius of the circles to look for. If your camera position is constant, this shouldn't change much. This code is taken from the matlab documentation page I linked. It doensn't find all the circles, but some tuning may help

```erlang
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRwUq.jpg');

%find circles doesn't work well on small images, I made the image
%three times larger, if you have larger images you should use those for
%better results
bim = imresize(im, 3*size(im));

%find and display circles
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(bim,[8 20],'ObjectPolarity','bright',...
    'Sensitivity',0.9);
imshow(bim);
h = viscircles(centers,radii);

number_of_bars = numel(centers)
```

I added green dots to circles the detector missed and blue X's over incorrect detection. I did these by hand, but the red circles were located by matlab.

[image]